# passed in const char* to a method but got char const * error instead

Tags: c++, char, constants

I encountered a wired problem on my C++ code. I'm using TCLAP software to accept command line arguments, and one of the flags is a file name:

```
TCLAP::ValueArg<string> Poly ("p", "poly",  "file name of the polynomial", false, "", "string");
```

I also have another function that accepts 3 parameters,

```
void GetBiPoly(const char *filename, BiPoly<BigFloat> *u, BiPoly<BigFloat> *v);
```

I'm passing the Poly string to the function `GetBiPoly` in this way:

```
benchmark::GetBiPoly(Poly.getValue().c_str(), &fxy, &gxy);
```

When I compile the program, it gives me the following error:

```
miranda.cpp:(.text+0x1900): undefined reference to `benchmark::GetBiPoly(char const*, CORE::BiPoly<CORE::BigFloat>*, CORE::BiPoly<CORE::BigFloat>*)'
```

It seems like the only difference is that the type of the file name in the error information is `char const*`, while the definition is `const char*`. Can anybody tell me what the problem it seems to be? Thanks.

Comment: The two forms are equivalent. You problem is you did not link to the implementation, or it's in another namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char const *` and `const char *` are exactly the same thing.  Your problem is not related to that part of the message.  Your error is that you're calling the function `benchmark::GetBiPoly()`, but the linker can't find it in the objects you're linking.  Where is that function defined?  Are you linking it?  Is it in that namespace?

Comment: You r right Carl, I messed up with the namespace, thanks for the quick response :) got a good lesson
By the way, are char const* and const char* the same? sorry i'm rather new in c++

Comment: @da_zhuang: Yes, they are the same.  Both are a pointer which is not `const` (you can store the address of some different variable into it if you like) pointing to a `char` which is viewed as `const` (you cannot use this pointer to modify the `char` it points to)